# Sqlalchemy query order

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm refactoring my flask app and am wondering how flask-sqlalchemy works - from right to left or vice versa.

For example, does this command first filter then order and select all, or select all, order, then filter?

```
items = db.session.query(MyDbModel).filter_by(status=1).order_by(desc('created')).all()
```

Comment: The database will filter based on the where clauses (filters) first, then finally order the data.

Comment: This question is really about Python, not flask nor sqlalchemy, and the answer is from left to right. It also makes sense: how can you filter and order something you didn't query yet?

Answer (score 0):

Translating to SQL it would be

```
SELECT * FROM MyDbModel
WHERE status = 1
ORDER BY created DESC
```

You can actually see the SQL query if you print the query before `all()` operator.

```
print(str(q))
```

Where `q` is your query object before `all()` function.
So, answering your question, it first filters, then order.

Comment: @Gepgecici2, did I answer your question?